# PHPMailer error Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465, timeout=300, options=array ()

Tags: php, email, ssl, phpmailer

Hi i am trying to use PHPMailer its not working giving me error

> Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465, timeout=300, options=array ()

here is my code

```
     require_once('mailFiles/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
echo (extension_loaded('openssl')?'SSL loaded':'SSL not loaded')."<br/>";
                $mail = new PHPMailer();
                $mail->isSMTP();
                $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
                $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    //            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
                $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    //            $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
    //            $mail->Host = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com:587';
    //            $mail->Port = 587;
                $mail->Port = 465;
                $mail->Username = "xs4arabiabahrain@gmail.com";
                $mail->Password = "mailpass";
                $mail->setFrom('mail@gmail.com', 'Firstz Last');
                $mail->addAddress('myemail@gmail.com', 'MAAGE-EMAIL User');
                $mail->IsHTML(true);

                //Set the subject line
                $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
                //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
                //convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
                $mail->msgHTML('Hi test 123');
                //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
                $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
                //Attach an image file
                //$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');
                $result = $mail->send();
                if (!$result) {
                    echo ("Mailer Error: "); 
                    echo ($mail->ErrorInfo);
                } else {
                    echo ("Message sent!"); 
                }
```

Have tired **tls** still not working.

Comment: $mail->Host = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com:587';

Comment: still not working now getting errors 

Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ()
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (10013)

Comment: I suggest you read the [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) and do what it says. Also sounds like you have restrictions on your PHP installation.

Comment: i am following this link i also get this code from here but not working in mine localhost as per php i have enabled open_ssl as well anything else require ..?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with my antivirus i am using McAfee you need to change its setting please follow this [link](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/we-are-unable-send-your-email-caused-mcafee) to change these settings.I hope it will help someone else also.